# visual c++ operator += is ambiguous

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

```
CString szMsg;

//Other non related code

//stOrderInfo.bstrOrderNum is defined as a _bstr_t
szMsg += ", Order: " + stOrderInfo.bstrOrderNum;
```

I'm converting the above from VS 6.0 to VS2k10 and I'm getting the following error (compiles in VS 6.0):

```
error C2593: 'operator +=' is ambiguous
```

What exactly does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've hard-coded **", Order: "** the compiler is having a hard time to decide which type it should be.

The obvious type should be `CString`, but it might try to make it to some other string type, and add the number to it.

So it probably can't decide if it's a `CString` or another string type. So it can't decide what type you're adding to szMsg.

You could just use a type cast:

```
szMsg += (CString)(", Order: ") + (CString)((char *)(stOrderInfo.bstrOrderNum));
```

Cast between string types:

[How to: Convert Between Various String Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I did this and then it just complains about concatenating the CString and _bstr_t (stOrderInfo.bstrOrderNum) at the end.  error C2666: 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::operator +' : 3 overloads have similar conversions

Comment: you are having ambiguous type casting here. Solution: explicit type casting. Cast the other one as well.

Comment: I tried that as well but the compiler doesn't allow you to cast it.  error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '_bstr_t' to 'CString'

Comment: You're right there wasn't an explicit conversion. I've fixed the answer, added a link that might help you in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This means that compiler cannot choose which + operation to use for BSTR + char concatenations. You have a mismatch of three types: CString, _bstr_t, and char.
Try to unify all three operands to a single type, e.g. to CString

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this but I may have no choice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `CString::operator+=` is known to have changed in Visual Studio 2010. For example in previous versions it handled embedded null characters OK, just like `operator+` keeps doing, but the new version doesn't. So it might be related to this.

EDIT
Link to discussion on this topic:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/c5d7f383-da80-4776-b9b8-a6065839bd87

Answer (score 0):

Better use `CString::AppendFormat`. But ensure you pass correct format-specifier.